# Why this javascript onkeypress event is not working?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if the problem is with my code or the browser, I have tried everything I know but can not find a solution.

Here is my Code:

```
var postcode = document.getElementById("deliveryPostcode");
    postcode.onkeypress = checkForDigits;
```

I have a form input, and I want to stop the user from entering non-digit characters. So only digits from 0-9 are allowed. But does not matter what I enter in the textbox I get the alert box. I am using firefox.

```
function checkForDigits(keyPressEvent) {
    var keyCode = keyPressEvent.keyCode;
    if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
        alert("Not a digit");
    }
}
```

Comment: See complete example from mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeypress

Comment: Change your alert to `alert("Not a digit: " + keyPressEvent.keyCode)`

Comment: thanks I get 'hello undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onkeypress has some issues with firefox try onkeydown it works fine

```
function checkForDigits(keyPressEvent) {
    var keyCode = keyPressEvent.keyCode;
    if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
        alert(keyCode);
    }
} 

var postcode = document.getElementById("deliveryPostcode");
    postcode.onkeydown = checkForDigits;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DF75c/2/)

Comment: Since this works you should vote it as the answer so people can quickly find it. @user3892337

Comment: @Richie Fredicson thanks there is another issue, when I enter a digit or other character and use backspace I get the alert box. Do you why this is?

Comment: @user3892337 it's because "backspace" has a keycode as well (8) http://jsfiddle.net/DF75c/4/

Comment: as Dehli mentioned its because your condition doesn't filter out "backspace key" [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DF75c/9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var postcode = document.getElementById("deliveryPostcode");
postcode.onkeyup = checkForDigits;
function checkForDigits(keyPressEvent) {
        var reg = /^\d+$/;
        var val=document.getElementById('deliveryPostcode').value
    if(!reg.test(val))
        alert('not a digit!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems that this might be the problem:

> In a keypress event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in
>   either the **keyCode** or **charCode** property, never both.

**[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode)**

Therefore, the actual cross-browser solution to this problem is to look which of the `keyCode` or `charCode` is used by the browser and read it accordingly.

```
var postcode = document.getElementById("deliveryPostcode");
postcode.onkeypress = checkForDigits;

function checkForDigits(event) {

    // Selects charCode or keyCode accordingly, based on which exists
    var chCode = ("charCode" in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;

    if (chCode < 48 || chCode > 57) {

        alert("Not a digit");

        // return false means that letter won't be placed to input
        return false;
    }

}
```

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/tzmEF/)**

Hence, for further reading I recommend: [keyCode property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqqripa.php)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something with your html. Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UbZh/1/). It's working for me in Chrome.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="deliveryPostcode">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok I tried it in Chrome it worked fine, but the problem is in FireFox. Even if i enter digits i get the alert box.

Comment: The author of this post said that it is occuring with firefox, so why you are telling about Chrome?

Comment: He said he's not sure if it's the browser's problem. Just confirming that it either is the browser or his html was wrong. @MaunoV.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your element with id "deliveryPostcode" is not textarea or input with type=text ?

```
<textarea id="deliveryPostcode">
</textarea>
```

here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G9Y6c/

Comment: thanks. the problem seems to be with Firefox. it works fine in Chrome. Any idea?